# Working with ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm completely new to Angularjs, I need some help in achieving the following requirement. Initially, i will be loading the following index.html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="controller/NextPageController.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main_wrapper" ui-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my app.js file;

```
'use strict';

var App = angular.module('myApp',['ui.router']);

App.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login")

    $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
        url: "/login",
        templateUrl: "views/login.html",
        controller: "NextPageController as nxtPgCtrl"
        })
        .state('nextpage', {
            url: "/nextpage",
        views: {
            "": {
                templateUrl: "views/nextpage.html"
            },
            "menu@nextpage": {
                templateUrl: "views/menu.html"
            },
            "footer@nextpage": {
                templateUrl: "views/footer.html"
            }
        }            
        })
        .state('nextpage.addemployee', {
            url: "/add-employee",
            templateUrl: "/views/addemployee.html"
        })
        .state('nextpage.listemployee', {
            url: "/list-employee",
            templateUrl: "/views/listemployee.html"
        })
        .state('nextpage.dashboard', {
            url: "/dashboard",
            templateUrl: "views/dashboard.html"
        })
}]);
```

I'm loading the login.html file inside the div block of index.html where I have used ui-view.

login.html;

```
<div id="login_form">
    <form ng-submit="nxtPgCtrl.nextPage()">
        <input type="text">
        <br>
        <input type="password">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Once the submit button is pressed I'm redirecting the user to the next page using the following controller.

NextPageController.js;

```
App.controller('NextPageController', ['$location', function($location) {
    var self = this;
    self.nextPage = nextPage;
    function nextPage() {
        $location.path('/nextpage');
    }
}]);
```

And this is my nextpage.html;

```
<div id="menu" ui-view="menu">

</div>
<div id="main_content" ui-view>
    <h3>This is main content...</h3>
</div>
<div id="footer" ui-view="footer">

</div>
```

This is the file that will be loaded inside the div where I have used ui-view="menu" in nextpage.html,

menu.html;

```
<div id="menu-items">
    <ul>
        <li><a ui-sref=".dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref=".addemployee">Add Employee</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref=".listemployee">List Employee</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And this file will be loaded inside the div where I have used ui-view="footer",

footer.html;

```
<h3>This is footer...</h3>
```

If I press the Dashboard, Add Employee & List Employee links the following respective files will be loaded inside the div block with id: main_content, since I have used ui-view.

dashboard.html;

```
<h3>This is main content...</h3>
```

addemployee.html;

```
<div id="add_employee">
    <h3>Add employee form...</h3>
</div>
```

listemployee.html;

```
<div id="list_employees">
    <h3>List of employees...</h3>
</div>
```

The above codes are working fine, but I need some help.

The first one is that, when I load nextpage.html, I want dashboard.html to be loaded inside the div block whose id is main_content. Now the code is like, I have hard coded the dashboard.html file content inside the div with id: main_content and if the user clicks the Dashboard link on the menu I'm loading the dashboard.html content. So, I have used the dashboard.html file content twice. Instead, I want the dashboard.html template to be loaded dynamically when I enter nextpage.html.

The next one is, whether this is the proper way of using ui-router to achieve what i'm trying in a web application or is there any standard way of doing this if any please guide me.

Comment: can you put your code in plunkr